# Make a "virtual port" which consists of multiple ports on Arduino

Tags: arduino, port, microcontroller, arduino-c++

I started using ports on Arduino instead of setting every pin low or high by hand. 
This is very useful and a lot faster. I am on a project, where i need at least one full port (8 bits) and at least one Serial Port.

I wanted to use the Arduino UNO but it has only one full port, port D.
 PD0 and PD1 are used for Serial communication. This means i can't use port D.

I was wondering if there is a possibility for me to merge multiple ports into a "virtual port". In the end i want something like this:

```
PORTX = 0b11111111; // the first 2 bits are PB0/PB1 and bit 3-8 are PD3-PD8
```

Is this possible in any way???

Comment: You can use all of port D. Just use software serial comms (bit-banging) for your serial port.

Comment: Id like to use all of port D _and_  Serial Communication. The pins D0 and D1 are hardwired to the USB so i think there is no way to use other pins for the Serial Communication

Comment: You don't need an actual serial port to do serial comms. You can use bit-banging using any GPIO pins  you have available. See https://www.georgetimmermans.com/arduino-serial-driver.html

Comment: It is possible, Using macros or small functions to read/write from/to the correct ports.

Comment: @Chimera yeah bitbanging is possible, but how do you wire your user-defined-serialport to USB (which is the most commonly used interface for the arduino)?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: I guess that the question was meant to be: "how can I achive it" and not "is it possible?" (even though the question is literally "is this possible in any way" ;-)

Comment: @TomMekken get an FTDI USB <=> serial converter and hook it up to your bit-banged pins. Works great.

Comment: @Chimera sure, but why buy additional hardware when the arduino already provides everything  you need? (especially when you leave the arduino-hardware unused)

Comment: @TomMekken I was providing a solution for the OP who wanted to used all of Port D.

Comment: @TomMekken Thanks for your idea, i kinda thought of something like this myself but i rather use the mega where i don't have to deal with this problem at all. I just wanted to know how easy it is to make a "virtual port". I know it is possible when using a IDE like Atmel Studio, where you can change virtually everything. But Arduino is very limited. Easy but limited. I actually didn't expect to find a solution. It's okay, i can always use the Mega or for project where size matters i can use the Arduino Micro which has more than enough Ports. I just thought it would be nice if it was possible.

Comment: sure thing. but how would it be easy, when using another IDE? AtmelStudio is just an Eclipse and Arduino IDE an ugly java-based text-editor. I always use qt-creator for everything, but I don't see how using a different IDE would change anything?! the `PORTS` are still plain addresses to internal registers of the MCU

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'yes' it is possible, but maybe not in the way you want it (or maybe I just don't know how to do so^^)

First of all, the `PORTS` are macros from Atmel. Your Arduino-Uno is based on the AtMega328p and therefore uses the AVR-Toolchain with all those `PORTS` under the hood.
If you were about to program your microcontroller without the arduino-bootloader and all the fancy arduino-library-stuff, you would address all your GPIOs that way.

If you have a look into the code of the Atmel-AVR Toolchain (that arduino is sitting on top of), you would see, that the `PORTS` are defined in `iom328p.h` and are only addresses of internal IO-registers within the microcontroller.

So, just declaring a virtual-Port is not that easy (maybe with a kind of memory mapping with something similar to `std::mmap()` but I've never tried this one).

Anyway you are a programmer, so there is a solution to almost everthing ;)
I personally would suggest, to create your own `Port`-Class:

- this class holds your required `Pins` as members and you have a setter, that overwrites your member-Pins according to the number you pass to it
- (this code is not meant to be the 'perfect' solution, just a quick hint into the direction)

I would recommend you to stay with the arduino-library for this approach. If you do it with the plain `PORTS`, you might mess up something somewhere. So for example if you init your SerialPort and afterwards do something like `PORTD |= (1<<PD0)`, you wont be able to receive any data and don't know why.

```cpp
class MyPort
{
private:
  uint8_t m_pin[8];
public:
  MyPort(uint8_t pins[8])
  {
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
      m_pin[i] = pins[i];       //copy from constructor-argument into member-variable
      pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT); //setting pin as OUTPUT
    }
  }

  void operator =(uint8_t val)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
      digitalWrite(m_pin[i], (val >> i)&1);
    }
  }
};

//            B0,B1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7
//             v  v  v  v  v  v  v  v
uint8_t pins[]{8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
MyPort PORTX(pins);

void setup()
{
  PORTX = 0b11001100;
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

**please note** that you will have to override the other operators as well, if you want bitwise addressing on your own port too